# Possible to set the "fileName" of an inline script tag that is displayed when errors occur?

Tags: javascript, onerror

If I have an inline script like whats below where the function foo is undefined, I want to be able to do something like:

```
<script fileName='foo.js'>
  foo();
</script>
```

and control what file name is displayed in the error console and/or to control what file name is passed to window.onerror when it handles the error.  eg, I want to control the url param that gets sent to

```
window.onerror = function (errMsg, url, line) {
    console.log(url); //would like this to output 'foo.js'
    console.log(event.filename);  //would like this to also output 'foo.js'
}
```

By default, unless a script links to an external file only the parent html file is listed but it would be very nice to be able to have inline code in different script tags state which script tag an error originated from.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Wouldn't that be confusing? The script isn't really in the file `foo.js` but in the document that the error actually says that it is. You have the line number in the document, isn't that enough to find the script tag in the document?

Comment: Unfortunately in chrome, if you create an iframe via document.write the line number that chrome gives you is not relative to the document, its relative to the script tag that the code is inside so its not sufficient.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12426039/document-write-and-window-onerror-weird-interaction-in-chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know javascript is oblivious to the HTML tags it is run inside. Could something like this work for you?

```
<script>
  try {
    foo();
    // the rest of the code...
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Caught error in foo.js');
    console.error(err);
  }
</script>
```

If you're adding these scripts dynamically to the page you should be able to wrap them with this try/catch code and get the desired effect.

Comment: The problem with that is if code in script A calls a function in script B which crashes it will be inside the try catch of script A, but I'd like to be told the error occurred in script B where the actually line that crashed is.  This also won't work if a function is called via body onload or something like that as it will bypass the try statement.

Comment: That's what the stack trace `console.error` spits out is for. I guess you could parse `err.stack` for specific keywords but I wouldn't put too much faith in that.

Comment: gotcha, that might be workable, although I think the body onload problem will still just bypass the try catch and be problematic.  If no one has anything better soonish I'll accept this :)